# Finding all possible set packings

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Say I have a matrix `S` of size `(m,n)`, where `m` is the number of sets, and `n` the number of all possible elements sets can have. In this matrix, if the entry `S(i,j)` is `1`, the set `i` has element `j`, and otherwise the element `S(i,j)` is `0`.

My question is: are there any known relatively efficient algorithms to enumerate **all possible set packings** (i.e. combinations of sets such that no two sets intersect)?

Using this representation, a packing `k` is defined as a vector 
`p_k = [p_{k,1}, p_{k,1}, ... p_{k,km}]` where the elements `p_{k,r}` are row indices in `S` (i.e. sets) such that the intersection of of the sets in `p_k` is `0`. Or in other words, the  inner product of any two row vectors `p_{k,r} * p_{k,s}'` indexed by `p_k` in `S` is `0`.

I'm looking for an implementation in MATLAB (or something callable from MATLAB), but if anybody knows of a fast implementation in some other library, that would also be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for set packings that contain _all_ elements (i.e. n elements at `1` when combined)?

Comment: Thanks @Laurent'. No; I am just looking for packings, i.e. unions of sets such that their intersection is empty.

Comment: Let's get it clear: each row is a valid set packing then.

Comment: Yes, @Laurent', that's correct, it's a packing of cardinality one (i.e. it only includes or "packs" one of the possible sets).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite efficient I fear, but surely more than brute force.

I understand that packings have cardinality ranging from 1 to (at most) m.

To find all possible solutions, start from cardinality 1 and iterate until:

- you reach `m`
- or there are no more *candidates* for the next iteration (more on this below).

The candidate matrix has the same form as `S`. At iteration n it contains the elements of the valid packing found at iteration n-1. It's initialized at iteration 1 with `S` values.

At each cardinality step

- for each row of the candidate matrix, you check wether you can build multiple packings that are still valid by adding one (and only one) row of matrix `S`:

  - You iterate through each row of `S` (this could be made faster if you skip rows that are  already in the packing itself). If it's valid, you append the considered row index to the packing, send this packing as a new result and add it to the **future, next iteration** candidate matrix (which will be smaller at each cardinality step, because some combination result in invalid packings).

This way, the candidate matrix is smaller and smaller at each iteration and you can stop as soon as there's no more candidates.

## Example

```
S=
 1 0 0 1  (a)
 1 1 0 0  (b)
 0 0 1 0  (c)
```

### Iteration 1

(initialization) : produce 3 results  and candidates : a, b and c (initialization)

**results**

```
(a,b,c)
```

**candidates**

```
 1 0 0 1  (a)
 1 1 0 0  (b)
 0 0 1 0  (c)
```

### Iteration 2

iterate on candidate, then on rows:

- take candidate a

  - skip row a (optimization 1)
  - try to combine it with row b -> fail
  - try to combine it with row c -> success

    - new results (ac) and new candidate (ac) for next time
- take candidate b

  - try to combine it with row a -> fail
  - skip row b (optimization 1)
  - try to combine it with row c -> success

    - new results (bc) and new candidate (bc) for next time
- take candidate c

  - skip a -> (already exists as a result)
  - skip c -> (already exists as a result)
  - skip row c (optimization 1)

**New results matrix**
    (a,b,c,ac,bc)

**New candidates matrix**

```
 1 0 1 1 (ac)
 1 1 1 0 (bc)
```

### Iteration 3

Same as above...

- take candidate (ac)

  - skip row a (optimization 1)
  - try to combine it with row b -> fail
  - skip row c (optimization 1)
- take candidate (bc)

  - try to combine it with row a -> fail
  - skip row b (optimization 1)
  - skip row c (optimization 1)

No more candidates: end.

**Final results matrix**
    (a,b,c,ac,bc)

**Final candidates matrix**

```
 ()
```

### About the optimizations

- optimization 1 is: no need to try to combine a row with a packing-candidate that already contains it

Comment: From what you described, the candidate matrix seems to get larger and larger at each iteration (which contradicts your last paragraph). Also, there are possibly multiple different packings of the same cardinality. Your algorithm, as it is, and if I understand correctly, would only find one packing of each cardinality.

Comment: @intrpc made some edits to clarify. Basically old candidates are removed from candidates matrix at each cardinality step, so the matrix diminishes. For the multiple packings: yes you have to iterate through every rows of the matrix at each cardinality step.

Comment: simply put: at each cardinality step, you're only concerned about **combining a packing** (from candidate list) **with a row**. That new packing will be a result as well as a new candidate for next step

Comment: Thanks @Laurent' for your help, I think you are headed in the right direction since you seem to be exploiting the dynamic-programming properties of the problem by reusing packings for higher cardinalities. However, I believe there are still some issues that need further clarification: **1.** Which matrix or matrices hold the final result at the end of your method? **2.** At each  "cardinality step", where do you add the rows of matrix `S` that are "valid"? **3.** What are such candidate rows valid with?

Comment: @intrpc I added an example to clarify. to answer your questions: *1*: another one, unshown. *2-3* for validity test you only have to check that the sum of the current candidate and the considered row is always < 1, for this you just do sum((candidate+row)>1) in matlab. *3* a row is valid with a candidate if it contains an 'orthogonal' set => it's a new packing

Comment: @intrpc sorry but I spent too much time on this, I must get back to real life sooner than later. Happy Coding, hope this leads you to some track of your own ;)

Comment: @intrpc extended the "example" part of my answer. Just _for the records_.

Comment: Thanks @Laurent'. I'll try to implement your solution and will update the OP to reflect how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be any polynomial-order algorithm to enumerate all possible packings for your problem, because there are exponentially many such packings.   For example, with m,n=3,4, there are 2^(n-1) packing configurations that include all n elements: {abcd}, {a}{bcd}, {ab}{cd}, {abc}{d}, {a}{b}{cd}, {a}{bc}{d}, {ab}{c}{d}, {a}{b}{c}{d}.  (Presumably sets are not distinguished; *e.g.* {abc}{d} equivalent to {d}{abc}.  If sets *are* distinguished, in following method just count up without excluding any counts, *i.e.* apply no rules.)

The rest of this answer may provide some ideas or a framework for solving the problem, but (as is) might not be particularly efficient.

One way to enumerate all valid cases is to count a base m+1 number H from H=0 up to a fraction of (m+1)^n, applying some rules to select valid configurations.  Let d.j denote the j'th digit of H, with d.1 least significant.  If d.j is 0, element `j` is a member of no set; if d.j = k > 0, `j` is a member of set `k`.  Let A.i(H) = highest location of digit `i` in H or `-i` if `i` doesn't occur; require A.i > A.(i+1).  A(H) can be maintained and tested incrementally in O(1) time as H counts up.  For example, to exclude 1323 (== 1232) in following (handmade) example, note that A.2(1323) = 2 < 3 = A.3(1323).

Example:  n = 4 = #elements; m = 3 = #sets;  H-sequence with indistinguishable sets should be: 0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0012, 0100, 0101, 0102, 0110, 0111, 0112, 0120, 0121, 0122, 0123, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1012, 1100, 1101, 1102, 1110, 1111, 1112, 1120, 1121, 1122, 1123, 1200, 1201, 1202, 1203, 1210, 1211, 1212, 1213, 1220, 1221, 1222, 1223, 1230, 1231, 1232, 1233.